# Why does padding an FFT in NumPy make it run much slower?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I had writted a script using NumPy's `fft` function, where I was padding my input array to the nearest power of 2 to get a faster FFT.

After profiling the code, I found that the FFT call was taking the longest time, so I fiddled around with the parameters and found that if I *didn't* pad the input array, the FFT ran several times faster.

Here's a minimal example to illustrate what I'm talking about (I ran this in IPython and used the `%timeit` magic to time the execution).

```
x     = np.arange(-4.*np.pi, 4.*np.pi, 1000)
dat1  = np.sin(x)
```

The timing results:

```
%timeit np.fft.fft(dat1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.3 µs per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(dat1, n=1024)
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.5 µs per loop
```

Padding the array to a power of 2 leads to a very drastic slowdown.

Even if I create an array with a prime number of elements (hence the theoretically slowest FFT)

```
x2    = np.arange(-4.*np.pi, 4.*np.pi, 1009)
dat2  = np.sin(x2)
```

The time it takes to run still doesn't change so drastically!

```
%timeit np.fft.fft(dat2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop
```

I would have thought that padding the array will be a one time operation, and then calculating the FFT should be quicker.
Am I missing anything?

**EDIT:** I was supposed to use `np.linspace` rather than `np.arange`. Below are the timing results using `linspace`

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.linspace(-4*np.pi, 4*np.pi, 1000)

In [4]: x2 = np.linspace(-4*np.pi, 4*np.pi, 1024)

In [5]: dat1 = np.sin(x)

In [6]: dat2 = np.sin(x2)

In [7]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.1 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.4 µs per loop

In [9]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat1, n=1024)
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.9 µs per loop
```

Padding still causes a slowdown. Could this be a local issue? i.e., due to some quirk in my NumPy setup it's acting this way?

Comment: Try the same test with larger arrays (e.g. near 32768).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - There's now a *massive* increase in performance when I pad it to a power of two (i.e., 32768). SO I'm guessing there's a cutoff where the performance increase starts to show.

Comment: For small arrays, the overhead (extra copying, other?) swamps the performance gain of using a power of 2.  The amount of overhead from using `n=1024` is surprising, but I haven't looked into the code to find the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `np.arange` when you want to be using `np.linspace`

```
In [2]: x     = np.arange(-4.*np.pi, 4.*np.pi, 1000)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([-12.56637061])
```

`np.arange` takes arguments (start, stop, step), whereas `np.linspace` is (start, stop, number_of_pts). When you calculate with the data I suspect you think you're using, you get the expected behavior:

```
In [4]: x = np.linspace(-4.*np.pi, 4.*np.pi, 1000)

In [5]: dat1 = np.sin(x)

In [6]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat1)
1 loops, best of 3: 28.1 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat1, n=1024)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.7 µs per loop

In [8]: x = np.linspace(-4.*np.pi, 4.*np.pi, 1009)

In [9]: dat2 = np.sin(x)

In [10]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 53 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit np.fft.fft(dat2, n=1024)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Ah, damn. I shouldn't be making "intelligent" observations this far past bedtime. Thanks for pointing out the stupidity!

Comment: I just tried it with `linspace` and I'm finding something similar to the original post. I've edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

FFT algorithms like NumPy's are fast for array sizes that factorize into a product of small primes, not just powers of two. If you increase the array size by padding the computational work increases. The speed of FFT algorithms is also critically dependent on the cache use. If you pad to an array size that creates less efficient cache use the efficiency slows down. The really fast FFT algorithms, like FFTW and Intel MKL, will actually generate plans for the array size factorization to get the most efficient computation. This includes both heuristics and actual measurements. So no, padding to the nearest power of two is only beneficial in introductory textbooks and not neccesarily in practice. As a rule of thumb you usually benefit from padding if the array size factorizes to one or more very large prime.